# Run PHP command in browser through bash script

Tags: php, bash, symfony

I'm working on my application in symfony2 and I'd like to make an installation file that could be run in a browser. The installation file asks user for some data and then runs a bash script which clones git repository, install composer and required components.

***install.php***

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $directory = htmlspecialchars($_POST['directory']);
        $db_loc = htmlspecialchars($_POST['db_loc']);
        $db_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['db_name']);
        $db_user = htmlspecialchars($_POST['db_user']);
        $db_password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['db_password']);

        exec("bash c.sh $directory $db_loc $db_name $db_user $db_password", $output);
        var_dump($output);
    } else {
        echo "
            <form action='install.php' method='POST'>
               //some html form content
            </form>
        ";
    }
?>
```

And this is file ***c.sh***

```
git init
git clone https://github.com/******** $1
cd $1 
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
```

When I'm runnig ***c.sh*** from putty with required parameter it works fine but when I'm trying to run ***install.php*** from browser works evertyhing besides last command : *php composer.phar install*. Is there a way to make it work in a browser or should I think something different? Thanks for replies!

Comment: you could od all that bash, in php

Comment: I tried that but the result is the same.